# Invoking jdk 7 compiled class from jdk6

Tags: java, java-7

I hava  class compiled using jdk7 and I am trying to invoke using JDK6 and the jars in classpath are compiled using jdk 6

```
jdk6/bin/java com.test.myclass -classpath abc.jar xyz.jar pqr.jar MNO.jar
```

my class `com.test.myclass` is present in `MNO.jar` and  `abc.jar xyz.jar pqr.jar` are compiled with jdk6

with jdk7 it works

```
jdk7/bin/java com.test.myclass -classpath abc.jar xyz.jar pqr.jar MNO.jar
```

This also fails.Any input to solve this problem.?

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/MyClass: unsupported classversion 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.test.MyClass.  Program will exit.
256
```

Thanks

Comment: you can't invoke jdk 1.7 class from jdk 1.6 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile the sources, give the parameter `-target 1.6`. That way 1.6 compliant bytecode will be generated (i.e. class files will indicate that they need 1.6 or higher to run).

Comment: @constantlearner So your program doesn't work at all? Then you should probably fix it before you worry about 1.6.

Comment: @constantlearner And are you going to tell what the error message is for jdk7, or did you think we are mind readers? Come on, help us help you.

Comment: I am trying to debug log please give me some time will upload the error sorry for inconvinience

Comment: @constantlearner It shouldn't take long, and you should've included the information in the initial post. Saying "it doesn't work" is the most useless thing a programmer (or tester or a client) can say.

Comment: I am doing this on client side it takes time and the scenario is complex here the jars are weblogic ones

Answer (score 2):

As the last resort you can change the class version at .class file from 33 to 32 (7-th byte from the file beginning) with a hex editor. If the class does not use any Java 7 new feature it will work OK.

Answer (score -1):

If you have used any jdk 7 specific code in your class then it won't work otherwise it should work.

Comment: No. The classfile will be marked for jdk 7 and won't run under it, unless you specify the -target when compiling.

Comment: @Kayaman Please read the question again, he asked for run the class file not compile, he already stated that he has compiled class using jdk 7 and want to invoke in jre 6.

Comment: I know. But if you don't specify the target during build, it will generate bytecode for 1.7, which will not run under 1.6.